# Alert Controll Message and NSURLSession

Tags: swift, delegates, nsurlsession

Im new guy in this, but used to search specific things over here, and since i couldn't find specific answers, maybe someone here can help out.

I'm basically learning and building an app.

At the moment i have build login, signup view controllers, etc..
 using php and mysql server.

Since im using and taking bit by bit pieces over the stack overflow

I have come across issue with a alert control message issue and NSURLConnection

Now i know that `NSURLConnection` is replaced by `NSURLSession`
but i cannot implemented it, its pretty damn hard to get around this.

My code is below:

```
let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = postData
request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var reponseError: NSError?
var response: NSURLResponse?

var urlData: NSData?
do {
    urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
} catch let error as NSError {
    reponseError = error
    urlData = nil
}
```

This gives me this issue

> sendSynchronousRequest(_:returningResponse:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h

How could i implement this to work with `NSURLSession`?

The second issue is with opening up the alert message

The `alertView.delegate = self` is the issue, i have tried several different things like replacing the alertView but it's not working, i tried alertController, etc. nothing works:

```
        if let error = reponseError {
            alertController.message = (error.localizedDescription)
        }

        alertView.delegate = self
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) { }
    }
} catch {
    let alertController:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign up Failed", message: "Server Error", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) { }
}
```

The issue is:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'alertView'

This is in a Swift file called `signup.VC`.

Comment: @HiDeo Thank you for modifying the post, looks like i will have to learn stack overflow too, of how to use it lol

Comment: Please only post one issue per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using synchronous requests, create an asynchronous request, and in the completion handler block, put all of the code that currently comes after the end of your catch block above so that it executes after the request completes.

I have no idea about your second issue, because you didn't include the code where you declared the alertView variable.